# Calculate a new value using another dataframe

Tags: pandas

I am looking for a way to divide all columns in a dataframe with the value of a column from another df. This can be done using any of the 2 options mentioned below.

```
df_amenity_normalized = df_amenity.apply( 
    lambda row: row / df_targets['Population'].loc[row.name], axis=1)
```

Or join the tables and then calculate:

```
ndf=df_amenity.merge(df_targets, left_index=True, right_index=True) 
ndft=ndf.apply(lambda x: x/ndf.Population, axis='rows' )
df_amenity_normalized1 = ndft.drop(columns=['Population', 'GNI', 'GDP', 'BM Dollar', 'HDI'])
```

Is there any other way to achive the same results?

---

Data is available here...

```
df_targets = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/njanakiev/osm-predict-economic-measurements/master/data/economic_measurements.csv', index_col='country')
df_targets.drop(columns='country_code', inplace=True)
df_targets = df_targets[['Population', 'GNI', 'GDP', 'BM Dollar', 'HDI']]

df_amenity = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/njanakiev/osm-predict-economic-measurements/master/data/country_amenity_counts.csv')
df_amenity.set_index('country', inplace=True)
df_amenity.drop(columns='country_code', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [df.div()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) function from pandas. See below:

```
df_amenity.div(df_targets['Population'], axis = 0)
```